# Â© instead of é saved in an utf-8 file

Tags: pandas, csv, encoding

I made a script in python using pandas to merge datas in a csv file. I think I mixed up the encoding while opening the file.

Now, If I open my file using UTF-8 encoding, I have Â© instead of "é", as if I was opening UTF-8 file using the Windows 1252 format. However, my file is opened as an UTF-8 file. So I guess, I saved the characters Â© in UTF-8 format.

Anyone knows how I can retrieve the correct data in this file? Is there a way, opening the file with a specific encoding and saving in another to retrieve the originals data?

EDIT :

To sum it up, what I did is :

- File A encoded in Windows-1252
- Opened/decoded it as UTF-8
- Encoded it in UTF-8 in File B
- Now when opening File B, I get datas that can't be like File A no matters if I decode it in UTF-8 or Windows-1252

I'm now in search of the sequence of decode/encode that will restore the original datas

Answer (score 1):

From your description's details (thank you for those!), we know that:

- The data in the file is actually in UTF-8, and
- The way you're opening/reading it is not using UTF-8 (probably using Windows-1252 or ISO 8859-1.

The byte sequence for `é` in UTF-8 is 0xC3 0xA9; if you read that byte sequence using Windows-1252 (for instance), you get `Â©`.

You've said:

> Now, If I open my file using UTF-8 encoding, I have Â© instead of "é"...

...but that symptom fairly clearly indicates that however you're opening and reading it is using Windows-1252 or similar, not UTF-8. So that's what you need to fix. The data in the file is in UTF-8.

Comment: Thank  you for your edit. 
I used SublimeText2 to open it in UTF-8, it indicates "Â©". Now if I open it in ANSI ("Reopen With encoding... -> Windows-1252") it indicates "ÃƒÂ©" instead of é. 

It's like I mess up at the start and opened it in wrong encoding, but after saved it, it now saved the wrong characters in UTF-8. ("Â©" encoded in UTF-8 instead of "é" encoded in UTF-8)

Comment: If I open it in ISO 8859-1, instead of "é" I have "ÃÂ©". 
I'm not sure I'm understandable, but to sum up, I think you're answer describe the original mistake, but in the end, I saved that mistake in an UTF-8 encoded format. So that if I open it in UTF-8, it looks like i'm decoding UTF-8-encoded-datas with Windows-1252. 
TLDR : My file is now a mess, and I wonder if I can reverse this

Comment: @T.Nel - It's certainly possible that it was originally opened using Windows-1252 or something and then saved as UTF-8, which would (as you say) embed `Â©` in it in their UTF-8 form. Blech. :-) I'm not sure how I'd handle that, since going the other way isn't 100% guaranteed. I'd probably open the file using UTF-8 and search for any character outside the range 32-127 and double-check/fix them. Not a lot of fun I'm afraid.

Comment: 500 000+ lines ! :') 
I wonder if I could just do a script that search/replace but I'm worried about data integrity. I still can regenerate the datas, but was searching for a quicker patch. 
Thanks for your answers I think i'll go for the second option.
I'll let the question open for a while just in case, i'll accept your answer if noone comes with a solution.

Comment: @T.Nel - Regenerating sounds like your best bet. :-)